# TypeCheckError: FlatMap and ParDo must return an iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am creating a google data flow pipeline using Apache beam 2.x & Python

Basically I have a text file with every new line containing a english sentence.

I am trying to call Google NLP (Sentiments) API for every new line / sentence.

So I have a function which calls the NLP API :

```
class CalculateSentiments(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    language_client = language.Client()
    pre_text = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', element)
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', pre_text)
    document = language_client.document_from_text(text)
    sentiment = document.analyze_sentiment().sentiment
    return sentiment.score
```

And I am using ParDo to call this function for every sentence. I am assuming, the following ParDo will call NLP sentiments api for every line from the text file automatically **( Basically I dont have to iterate through every line in the text file !?)**

```
output = lines | beam.ParDo(CalculateSentiments())

output | WriteToText(known_args.output)
```

But I get this error after I execute the data flow:

> **TypeCheckError: FlatMap and ParDo must return an iterable.  was returned instead.** [while running
>   'ParDo(CalculateSentiments)'] Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Users/gsattanthan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/executor.py",
>   line 297, in **call**
>       evaluator.process_element(value)   File "/Users/gsattanthan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/transform_evaluator.py",
>   line 366, in process_element
>       self.runner.process(element)   File "/Users/gsattanthan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py",
>   line 267, in process
>       self.reraise_augmented(exn)   File "/Users/gsattanthan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py",
>   line 263, in process
>       self._dofn_simple_invoker(element)   File "/Users/gsattanthan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py",
>   line 198, in _dofn_simple_invoker
>       self._process_outputs(element, self.dofn_process(element.value))   File
>   "/Users/gsattanthan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/typehints/typecheck.py",
>   line 60, in process
>       return self.wrapper(self.dofn.process, args, kwargs)   File "/Users/gsattanthan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/typehints/typecheck.py",
>   line 84, in wrapper
>       return self._check_type(result)   File "/Users/gsattanthan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/typehints/typecheck.py",
>   line 98, in _check_type
>       % type(output))

What Am I doing wrong ? The way I use Pardo is very similar as shown in Apache beam doco !

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, wrapping the return variable with square brackets fixed it.

Now it makes sense, why the error says it needs to be iterable !

> return [sentiment.score]